# ATOM Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Micheale\CS50\projects\project1\src'

Tags: reactjs

I am using ATOM & new to ReactJS. I have installed the package using npm i react-native
I can see it via package.json

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "expo": "^37.0.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-split": "^2.0.7"
  },
```

**I got error:**

```
    ./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Micheale\CS50\projects\project1\src'
```

Please advise.

Regards,

Micheale

Comment: How did you import react native ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your may have imported react-native in a wrong way. Make sure that is in quotes;
e.g,

```
import {View} from 'react-native'
```

If this is not the problem and your syntax is all right, then it may be some setup problem. Then i will recommend **EXPO** which by just one command sets up everything necessary for writing react-native locally.
First dowmload the expo-cli;
In your command line;

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

After it gets installed, run this command to create a project;

```
expo init name_of_project
```

That is it. Everything will be done and now you just have to start writing some code.